Aws run lambda when task is healthy
I want my lambda to run once when the ecs task becomes healthy (the essential container becomes healthy). In my lambda i need to get the essential container ip and port and send a request to it, after that i use the response to register the container app with third party application. Could you please help me in finding out how to do it, which events to use? Thanks in advance
I've read about task state change event, but i do no think this is a good approach, because i need the essential container application to be up and running to use the endpoint. I also know about the TASK_SET_HEALTHY event , but i am not sure that it is sent to event bridge by default, and i am not sure that i can get the needed task id from this event

One of the best ways of figuring out which event do you need is using api integration on a rule of default event bus and make it match it all (or filter by service). On your api integration you can configure the url of request catcher o webhook.site or any other web that let you see the request body. Btw im looking in cloudtrail any avents that could match with ecs container healthchecks and i cant find anything... perhaps you can send a custom event to event bridge using aws sdk if you cant find any suitable event
